# JPQL Exception for composite key

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, jpql

I am unable to know the solution for 2 JPQL Exception

1. subquery must return only one column The field
2. `[PARENTENTITY.PARENTID2]` in this expression has an invalid table in
   this context
   for following entity  --

---

```
    class ParentEntity{
      @Id
      String parentId1;
      @Id
      String parentId2;
      @ManyToOne
      ChildEntity childEntityRef;
    }
```

---

```
    class ChildEntity {  
      @Id
      String childId1; 
      @Id
      String childId2;
    }
```

---

when i tried Query -
 `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where me <> ALL(Select pe.childEntityRef From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )`
it gives following exception -

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6069] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The field [PARENTENTITY.PARENTID2] in this expression has an invalid table in this context.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidTableForFieldInExpression(QueryException.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.validateNode(FieldExpression.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression.normalize(Expression.java:2978)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.DataExpression.normalize(DataExpression.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.FieldExpression.normalize(FieldExpression.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.CompoundExpression.normalize(CompoundExpression.java:218)
```

when i tried Query -
 `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where me <> (Select pe.childEntityRef From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )`
it gives following exception -

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery must return only one column
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE ( <> (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILDENTITY t1 ON ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1)) WHERE ((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?))))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=ChildEntity sql="SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE ( <> (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN CHILDENTITY t1 ON ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1)) WHERE ((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?))))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:535)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery must return only one column
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 2.4 or 2.5 release, there have been a lot of JPQL enhancements and fixes.  Although what you are trying doing my still not be possible the way you are trying to do it.

Try simplifying your query,

```
SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where not exists (Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 and pe.childEntityRef = me)
```

or,

```
SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where not exists (Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 and pe.childEntityRef.childId1 = me.childId1 and pe.childEntityRef.childId2 = me.childId2)
```

In 2.5 you should also be able to do,

```
SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where (me.childId1, mew.childId2) NOT IN (Select pe.childEntityRef.childId1, pe.childEntityRef.childId2 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

James , Please clarify about the exception defined below (In response to your query described) ...
 *Using Eclipselink 2.5 release [eclipselink-2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]*

---

JPA Query 1)  `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where not exist (Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 and pe.childEntityRef = me)`

**Output-**

```
    Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where not exist (Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 and pe.childEntityRef = me)], line 1, column 70: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(81!=[652:1: simpleConditionalExpressionRemainder[Object left] returns [Object node] : (n= comparisonExpression[left] | (n1= NOT )? n= conditionWithNotExpression[(n1!=null), left] | IS (n2= NOT )? n= isExpression[(n2!=null), left] );])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.unexpectedToken(JPQLException.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.addError(JPQLParser.java:245)
```

---

JPA Query 2)  `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where not exist (Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 and pe.childEntityRef.childId1 = me.childId1 and pe.childEntityRef.childId2 = me.childId2)`

**Output-**

```
 Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where not exist (Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 and pe.childEntityRef.childId1 = me.childId1 and pe.childEntityRef.childId2 = me.childId2)], line 1, column 70: unexpected token [(].
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(81!=[652:1: simpleConditionalExpressionRemainder[Object left] returns [Object node] : (n= comparisonExpression[left] | (n1= NOT )? n= conditionWithNotExpression[(n1!=null), left] | IS (n2= NOT )? n= isExpression[(n2!=null), left] );])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.unexpectedToken(JPQLException.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.addError(JPQLParser.java:245)
```

---

JPA Query 3)  `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where (me.childId1,me.childId2) NOT IN (Select pe.childEntityRef.childId1, pe.childEntityRef.childId2 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )`

**Output-**

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8024] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where (me.childId1,me.childId2) NOT IN (Select pe.childEntityRef.childId1, pe.childEntityRef.childId2 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )], line 1, column 72: syntax error at [,].
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(79!=82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.syntaxErrorAt(JPQLException.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:304)
```

---

But PostgreSQL query working prefectly:

SQL Query 1)

```
SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where NOT EXISTS (
Select pe.parentId1 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=? and pe.parentId2=?
 and pe.childId1 = me.childId1 and pe.childId2 = me.childId2)
```

SQL Query 2)

```
SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where (me.childId1,me.childId2) NOT IN (
Select pe.childId1, pe.childId2  From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=? and pe.parentId2=?)
```

---

---

**Updated :**

For 3rd JPA Query )  `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where (me.childId1,me.childId2) NOT IN (Select pe.childEntityRef.childId1, pe.childEntityRef.childId2 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )`

**Output-**

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-06-18 19:21:54.407--UnitOfWork(15545028)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "childentity"
Error Code: 0
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Call: SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "childentity"
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Error Code: 0
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=ChildEntity sql="SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))")
Call: SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=ChildEntity sql="SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at com.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:27)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "childentity"
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=ChildEntity sql="SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:679)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "childentity"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327)
```

---

Postgresql Query ) `SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTITY.CHILDID1, CHILDENTITY.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))`

**Output-**

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "childentity"
LINE 3: ....CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (CHILDENTIT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "t0".

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "childentity"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "t0".
Character: 62
```

---

Updated Postgresql Query ) -- Alias CHILDENTITY  replaced by t0 then working perfectly -

```
 SELECT t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2 FROM CHILDENTITY t0 WHERE (t0.CHILDID1, t0.CHILDID2) NOT IN (SELECT t1.CHILDID1, t1.CHILDID2 FROM PARENTENTITY t2, CHILDENTITY t1 WHERE (((t2.PARENTID1 = ?) AND (t2.PARENTID2 = ?)) AND ((t1.CHILDID2 = t2.CHILDID2) AND (t1.CHILDID1 = t2.CHILDID1))))
```

---

Comment: Well, to start, you are using 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600 as the error states, not 2.5 as you state...

Comment: Also, I had a typo, it is EXISTS not EXIST

Comment: Both 1 and 2 query working now perfectly (becoz EXISTS not EXIST)

Comment: 3rd JPA Query `SELECT me.childId1,me.childId2 FROM ChildEntity as me where (me.childId1,me.childId2) NOT IN (Select pe.childEntityRef.childId1, pe.childEntityRef.childId2 From ParentEntity as pe where pe.parentId1=:parentId1 and pe.parentId2=:parentId2 )` ( supported in Eclipselink 2.5 ) not working because of **Alias problem in native sql query** . Is it bug in eclipselink 2.5 or any problem in JPA Query .